# Show appbar button if item is selected

Tags: list, xaml, microsoft-metro, appbar

I am writing an app with an appbar and item list. I want to add some buttons to the appbar which should appear only when the list item is selected.

So, how to show an additional button on an appbar when the item of the list is selected?

This is Windows 8 Metro style C#/XAML application.

Answer (score 3):

```
<AppBar x:Name="bottomAppBar" IsOpen="True" IsSticky="True">
```

...

```
private void itemGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (itemGridView.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        nextButton.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;
    }
    else
    {
        nextButton.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the additional app bar button and set its `Visibility` property to `Collapsed`.
In the `SelectionChanged` event handler of the list, set the buttons `Visibility` property to either `Visible` or `Collapsed` depending on whether the list item is being selected or deselected.

Answer (score 1):

Set `AppBar.IsOpen` property instead of `Visibility`.

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer, but yes you are right. Set the button's Visibility and the app bar's IsOpen.